# I got an error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" when I try to get a phone number in contact

Tags: ios

```
if let phone:ABMultiValueRef = ABRecordCopyValue(con,kABPersonPhoneProperty).takeRetainedValue()
   {
        for (var k = 0 ; k < ABMultiValueGetCount(phone) ; ++k){
            //获取电话Label
            var personPhoneLabel:String   = ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel(ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phone, k).takeRetainedValue()).takeRetainedValue()as String
            //获取該Label下的电话值
            var personPhone:String = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phone, k).takeRetainedValue() as! String
            phoneNum = personPhone
            print(personPhoneLabel+":"+personPhone)
        }
    }
    else{
        phoneNum = ""
    }
```

the error line is the first line:

```
 if let phone:ABMultiValueRef = ABRecordCopyValue(con, kABPersonPhoneProperty).takeRetainedValue()
```

why the "if let" doesn't work?

Comment: What is `con`, what is `kABPersonPhoneProperty`?

Comment: con is an ABAddressBookRef variable. and kABPersonPhoneProperty is a property of contact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ABRecordCopyValue can return nil, so you need to check it before you call takeRetainedValue() on the returned value

Edit - do something like

```
let copiedValue = ABRecordCopyValue(con,kABPersonPhoneProperty)
if let phone = copiedValue?.takeRetainedValue() {
....
```

Comment: thank you!  I have solved my problem by using you code!

Comment: Glad to help. And please accept as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem. And the right code like:

```
if let unmanagedPhone = ABRecordCopyValue(con, kABPersonPhoneProperty){
        var phone:ABMultiValueRef = unmanagedPhone.takeUnretainedValue()

        if let unmanagedPhoneNumberArray = ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(phone){
            var phoneNumberArray = unmanagedPhoneNumberArray.takeUnretainedValue() as NSArray
            phoneNum = phoneNumberArray[0] as! String
        }
    }
    else{
        phoneNum = ""
    }
```